# How far do I need to be from a creature to be outside its reach?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, reach

I had my wood-elf beside a scarecrow. I moved 35 feet away, and then on its turn the scarecrow moved 30 feet after me.

My character is now five feet away from a scarecrow, because I have five more movement than it. The scarecrow’s stats say it has a five-foot range on its melee attack. Can this attack hit my elf? The rules say within 5 feet, but the other player says that it’s technically 5 feet so it can hit me.

Answer (score 29):

This is one of those times where's it's more helpful to think in squares than feet. Lets start by converting to squares and then work backwards to feet.

To start, you and the scarecrow are within 5' of one another (in close melee range or whatever). In 5' square terms, you are adjacent.

When you move 35', you are moving 7 5' squares. When the scarecrow moves 30', he is moving 6 5' squares. This puts you 5' or *1 square* away from each other, or out of 5' melee reach.

So if you are in melee range, and move 35', and the scarecrow moves 30', you are *out* of melee range.

Here's a diagram that [SevenSidedDie](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/321/sevensideddie) created that is super helpful in visualizing this (the light red is the 5-foot reach of the scarecrow):

[image: Illustration of 30 vs 35 ft movement]

It's helpful to think of yourself in the center of a square when thinking about distance, because no one can be *in* your space (or square or circle or hex or however you're choosing to model your battlefield). You *occupy* that space and unless a creature is significantly bigger or smaller than you, no one can share your space.

Comment: Here's a diagram I just whipped up for an answer. I was too slow, but you might want to use it: http://i.stack.imgur.com/xHfkP.png

Comment: @SevenSidedDie thanks! I would have done one myself but I can't upload from here :(

Answer (score 22):

Here's an alternative answer that's a little less square.

The flaw in your reasoning is that you treat your initial distance as zero feet away from the scarecrow. This is unlikely to be correct... It would mean that either you were in exactly the same place as the scarecrow, or at the very least giving it a very close hug.

So, suppose that you are very, very, close to the scarecrow. 0.1 feet away, which puts your nose well within its personal space.

You move 35 feet, and end up 35.1 feet from the scarecrow.

The scarecrow moves, and ends up 30 feet from where it started.

The difference between 35.1 feet and 30 feet is 5.1 feet. Which is (just) outside its reach.

By convention, characters "in melee" are typically considered to be five feet from each other. The math works the same for any non-zero distance, though.

Comment: You mean *5.1 feet is (just) outside its reach*, I believe.